# Render template based on the name of the endpoint in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm looking to make the code more maintainable.  Right now "thing1" is repeated three times.  Is there a way to make this

```
@app.route("/thing1")
def thing1():
     return render_template("thing1.ejs")

@app.route("/thing2")
def thing2():
     return render_template("thing2.ejs")

@app.route("/thing3")
def thing3():
     return render_template("thing3.ejs")
```

More like...

```
@app.route("/thing1")
def thing1():
     return render_template_name_of_function() # should render thing1


@app.route("/thing2")
def thing2():
     return render_template_name_of_function() # should render thing2

@app.route("/thing3")
def thing3():
     return render_template_name_of_function() # should render thing3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read function infos by using `inspect` module, to get the currently function name:

```
import inspect

@app.route("/thing1")
def thing1():
     return render_template(inspect.stack()[0][3])

@app.route("/thing2")
def thing2():
     return render_template(inspect.stack()[0][3])

@app.route("/thing3")
def thing3():
     return render_template(inspect.stack()[0][3])
```

Then, you can specify a extension to template file, after the `inspect.stack()` call, such as `inspect.stack()[0][3] + '.html'`

Answer (score 2):

This is how it **would** be done.

```
@app.route("/thing1")
def thing1():
     return render()

@app.route("/another_thing1")
def another_thing1():
     return render()

@app.route("/yet_anther_thing1")
def yet_antoher_thing1():
     return render()

def render():
    return render_template("thing1.ejs")
```

Although, unless you think it is absolutely necessary, I would argue it **should** be done by using `redirect("thing1")`.

Comment: Ahh sorry... editied question to make it more clear.  Each function needs to render a template that is the same name as the function